# Ent Lib 6 / Unity 3: Injecting a dependency into a CustomTraceListener

Tags: .net, unity-container, enterprise-library, ioc-container

CONTEXT:

I am using Enterprise Library 6 and Unity 3 throughout my solution to manage cross cutting concerns and as a lightweight container for managing Dependency Injection. I have a requirement to develop a Custom Trace Listener. I need to inject a dependency into that Custom Trace Listener.

This functionality is available in Enterprise Library 5 and Unity 2. The following link provides a nice example of how it can be achieved (my own requirements are almost similar to those outlined in the link):

[Unity / EntLib: Injecting a dependency into a CustomTraceListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438362/unity-entlib-injecting-a-dependency-into-a-customtracelistener)

However, it seems as though it is not a straightforward migration in Enterprise Library 6, for the following reasons:

The Ent Lib 6 TraceListenerData class no longer makes available an override against the:

`GetCreationExpression()`

...method. In Ent Lib 6 the new functionality is provided in the:

`CoreBuildTraceListener()`

...method. My understanding is that the Ent Lib 5 `GetCreationExpression()` allowed 'marker's' to be placed in the returned expression that could be substituted when the Unity Container was resolved. The new `CoreBuildTraceListener()` returns a new instance of the Trace Listener.

Also, Enterprise Library no longer uses the Unity container to resolve instances. The:

`EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension`

...has been removed. The new approach would be something along the lines of:

container.RegisterInstance(logWriterFactory.Create());

However, for me this means that the CoreBuildTraceListener() is invoked (on logWriterFactory.Create()) before any call can be made to resolve a Interface through the Unity Container.

QUESTION(s):

Using Enterprise Library 6 and Unity 3, is it possible to either:

a. Get a hold of the Unity Container in the `CoreBuildTraceListener()` method at the correct time - so I can find the appropriate Interface I need to inject into my Custom Trace Listener when the Custom Trace Listener is created or...

b. Is there a new approach to achieving the same end-goal that I don't know about (if possible, please could you provide a simple example?) or...

c. Has this functionality regressed?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. Further information on the topic can be found referencing the following link:

https://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/461536